# Create a neighbourhood graph from a list of voxels faster than in O(n^2)?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, voxel, neighbours

I'm currently creating a "neighbourhood graph" by doing roughly this:

```
for every voxel
  look at every other unseen voxel 
    check if neighbours
```

which runs roughly in n squared (minus n). It is acceptable for a certain number of voxels, but obviously it takes much more time with bigger lists.

Another naive solution is simply to put everything into either a big 3d array, or in a hashmap, which would run in O(n) but at the expense of much more memory.

Is there a faster way? I can't seem to enter the right search terms in google...

Comment: The hash approach requires relatively little memory. It depends of your implementation language, but roughly the equivalent to 5 or 6 pointers/integers per point.

Comment: If you have a 3d-array of evenly spaced voxels, then finding neighbors is trivial (+/- 1 in each index).  If you are currently storing some information of each voxel in a large 1-d array, reshaping to a 3-d array does not change the size of your data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to look at space partitioning trees like the [octree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree) or [k-d tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) structures.  These structures usually can be built very efficiently (O(n) or O(n log n), IIRC), and then provide extremely fast lookups for finding either nearest neighbors or points within a given bounding box.  Using one of these structures should give you a huge performance boost without the huge memory cost of making a giant 3D array.

Hope this helps!

Comment: "for finding either nearest neighbors or points within a given bounding box." How is this bounding box defined?

Comment: These data structures let you do queries of the form “here’s a 2D or 3D box - what are all the points inside this box?”